# Json.Net - What does the $. do?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I'm reading up about newtonsoft json.net.

An example for selecting a token and deciding to create or not create an error is given as...

`result = (string)items.SelectToken(@"$.[0]['Name']", errorWhenNoMatch: true);`

The page where this is referred is at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ErrorWhenNoMatchQuery.htm

I have no idea what the $. does.  Does anyone know what it does?

Comment: https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This syntax uses [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) or "XPath for JSON". `$` is just the root object/element.

Comment: thanks, I never knew that a XPath equivalent existed in json.